# How to post image and array together with react native to backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, post, fetch

I am trying to send an image file and  data (object or array) to a backend with react native. I tried using fetch and the code below and got it to send an image to backend. But my target is to send the image and data together. How can I achieve this?

```
uploadPhoto = async (response) => {


 

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileToUpload', {
      uri: response.path,
      name: 'image',
      type: response.mime,
      imgPath: response.path
    });

    const infos={ad:'onur',soyad:'cicek'};



    try {

      const rest = await fetch('https://www.birdpx.com/mobile/fotografyukle/'+this.state.user.Id, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        body: formData
        });

        const gelenVeri = await rest.text();
        let convertedVeri=JSON.parse(gelenVeri);

        console.log(convertedVeri);
        return false


      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

  };
```

I need to post `const infos={ad:'onur',soyad:'cicek'};`  and the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in formData itself

```
formData.append('other_infos', infos);
```

Here `other_infos` will be key that required to extract from backend, you can append n number of parameters in `FormData`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding other data to the FormData.
like in the example

```
formData.append('infos', infos);
```